# No action After click on Button

Tags: android

I created one button in my android app,but when i am clicking on that button,nothing happens.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_data);
    search =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Search);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                new retrievedata().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do you see any exception in the log??. I suggest you remove the try catch

Comment: May be problem is in AsyncTask. Print some value in log.

Comment: Every thing looks fine if your not doing blunder at your end..

Comment: Post the complete code & necesary  Logcat outputs.Otherwise we can't help you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize the button in OnCreate();

Answer (score 0):

Try to put asyncTask calling to a function and call function under onClick